# Rails: How to make a setter method find_or_create within an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, getter-setter

I I have a `Project` model that belongs_to `Company` and to `Notary`. `Notary` belongs_to `Company`.

In my `Project`model I have the following getter / setter methods:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :notary

      # getter method for Notary
      def notary_name
        notary.try(:name)
      end

      # setter method
      def notary_name=(name)
        self.notary = Notary.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?
      end
end
```

The setter method checks if a certain Notary exists or else creates a new record.

The issue with this is that if a user with another `Company` inputs an existing Notary name it will NOT create a new record.

The syntax should be something like:

`self.notary = current_company.notaries.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?`

However `current_company` is not available at the model-level. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you want `self.notary = company.notaries.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?`, which will find or create a notary under the scope of the project's company. You may want to elaborate more on your domain, and why you want to do a find-or-create here.

Comment: it seems as if `company` is Nil here and is only assigned to the model later. (I can call self.company in a before_save filter, but not in my setter method)

Comment: Seems that there's no way for your code to determine which Company it should be looking under for its Notary. I would suggest one of two options: 1, make sure company is set on your project before assigning the `notary_name` attribute (`project.companies.create(...)` ought to do that), or 2, remove these accessor methods from your model and pass the notary record to it directly. A validation could ensure that the notary's company matches the project's company. If you post the code that creates the project and assigns notary_name, that might help.